# kivy is giving me errors for config.ini and config.py

Tags: python, terminal, kivy, game-development

Following error occurred while running my application:

```
mhpolymath@Haidars-MacBook-Pro invaders % python app.py
\[WARNING\] \[Config      \] Older configuration version detected (21 instead of 27)
\[WARNING\] \[Config      \] Upgrading configuration in progress.

**\[ERROR  \] Error while activating FileHandler logger
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mhpolymath/miniconda3/envs/flapgame/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kivy/config.py", line 598, in write
with open(self.filename, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fd:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied: '/Users/mhpolymath/.kivy/config.ini'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mhpolymath/miniconda3/envs/flapgame/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kivy/logger.py", line 310, in emit
self.\_configure()
File "/Users/mhpolymath/miniconda3/envs/flapgame/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kivy/logger.py", line 283, in \_configure
FileHandler.fd = open(filename, 'w', encoding=FileHandler.encoding)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied: '/Users/mhpolymath/.kivy/logs/kivy_24-01-15_0.txt'
\[ERROR  \] Unable to write the config \</Users/mhpolymath/.kivy/config.ini\>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/mhpolymath/miniconda3/envs/flapgame/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kivy/config.py", line 598, in write
with open(self.filename, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as fd:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: \[Errno 13\] Permission denied: '/Users/mhpolymath/.kivy/config.ini'**

\[INFO   \] \[Kivy        \] v2.3.0
\[INFO   \] \[Kivy        \] Installed at "/Users/mhpolymath/miniconda3/envs/flapgame/lib/python3.12/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
\[INFO   \] \[Python      \] v3.12.0 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Oct  2 2023, 12:22:05) \[Clang 14.0.6 \]
\[INFO   \] \[Python      \] Interpreter at "/Users/mhpolymath/miniconda3/envs/flapgame/bin/python"
\[INFO   \] \[Logger      \] Purge log fired. Processing...
\[INFO   \] \[Logger      \] Purge finished!
\[INFO   \] \[Image       \] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
\[INFO   \] \[Factory     \] 195 symbols loaded
\[INFO   \] \[Text        \] Provider: sdl2
\[INFO   \] \[Audio       \] Providers: audio_sdl2 (audio_ffpyplayer, audio_avplayer ignored)
```

I installed all modules that were needed and now when I ran `python app.py` I got these two errors.
I am still a beginner with python and using terminals, so can someone please explain what the errors are indicating? so I can understand how to fix them.

Comment: You are running the code as a user account that does not have permission to read/write those files.  Presumably they are owned by some other user account.

Comment: @JohnGordon but I downloaded/created these files on this user (and it is set to admin) so I don't know what could be the problem

Comment: Please post the output of your code in fixed point font. We can not see, which part of the line the ^^^^^^^^ relates to.

Comment: @user1934428 Sorry I don't know how to use the tens of formatting options on this website. they are extremely confusing and vague to my brain. Someone suggested an edit I approved it, and I hope it helps everyone read the post better now.

Comment: Well, it does help. Don't you think yourself, that it is better readable now? Actually, the [formatting is pretty simple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), basically it is Markdown.

Comment: As for the error: Did you check the permissions of your `.kivy/config.ini`? You didn't post this in your question.

Comment: @user1934428 It was clear on my end before the change. I cannot understand markdown (I'm really a novice in tech and I just started using this website so please bare with me)

Comment: @user1934428 I don't know how to check the permission for that. Is it a file somewhere? or how do I do that in terminal?

Comment: `ls -ld FILENAME` or `stat FILENAME`.

Comment: @user1934428 I'm afraid to ask... but which file? ('^_^)
is .kivy/config.ini a file on its own?

Comment: @user1934428 I tried running `ls -ld .kivy/config.ini` in the terminal and got the following: `-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff  1202 Aug 26  2021 .kivy/config.ini`.  
I tried running `stat .kivy/config.ini` and got: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 0 1202 "Aug 31 21:00:44 2021" "Aug 26 21:08:21 2021" "Aug 26 21:08:21 2021" "Aug 26 21:08:21 2021" 4096 8 0 .kivy/config.ini`.  
What does that mean?

Comment: Put this information into the question, not into a comment.

Comment: _is .kivy/config.ini a file on its own?_ : Most likely it is a file, not a directory, because people often call a file SOMETHING.ini, if it is a text file with the content of an ini-file. However, since I couldn't be 100% sure, I told you to use `ls -ld` and `stat`, which would both work with files or directories. BTW, in the future, to find out WHAT is behind a directory entry, you can do a, i.e., `file .kivy/config.ini`, which makes an educated guess of what it is. Not always correct, but pretty reliable.